# how to upload an image from inside my iOS app to my server

Tags: ios, image, upload

i need a help to find the code to let me upload an image from my iOS app to my server, for more information, the image will not upload from my own iPhone it will be inside the app then i will upload it to my server and the server will give me link for that image.so i can share that link with every one.

Comment: yes, but i didn't find the way. i found many answers but they are not that near to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly not clear question. 
But, I would suggest you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) where you can find right solution for your needs.

Comment: thank you , i will look there. to make it more clear, i have an iOS app, inside the app there are a lot of images and i need to upload them for inside the app to any server to get a link of that images. is it clear?